# Schröder-Bernstein for abelian groups with direct summands

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups

What is a simple example of two abelian groups $A,B$ which are isomorphic to direct summands of each other (that is, $A \cong B + C$ and $B \cong A + D$ for some abelian groups $C,D$), but which are not isomorphic?

Currently I only know the following: [There are](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3) abelian groups $A$ with $A \cong A^3$ but $A \not\cong A^2$. Then we may take $B=A^2$. However, the construction of these $A$ is quite complicated, as far as I know.

Comment: Searching for [cantor bernstein abelian groups](https://www.google.com/search?q=cantor+bernstein+abelian+groups) returns a paper [Don Laackman: The Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Property in Cateogries](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Laackman.pdf). The author gives an example in Example 3.1. (I did not check the details.)

Comment: Interesting, but in the paper the CSB property is considered w.r.t. arbitrary monomorphisms (not necessarily split). Indeed, the monomorphisms in the example are non-split.

Comment: I've asked a special case here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/218113